# How to integrate Orbeon and another Spring Web application running in separate Tomcat server?

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, orbeon

I am new to Orbeon. My company has a requirement to integrate our Spring MVC application with Orbeon. I read many posts about deploying Orbeon and Spring app war files separately but mostly within the same Tomcat container by using crossContext config. Is there a way to have both applications running on separate tomcat servers? If so, are there examples available online?

Answer (score 0):

Orbeon Forms 4.7 will have a built-in embedding solution, see [Server-side Form Runner embedding #1808](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/1808). Until that is done, there is no good solution.